# A function that finds two numbers out of an array that add up to the given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, addition

I am currently trying to make a function that finds two numbers from a random array and find which two add up to the given number. It just needs to tell me what index the two numbers are on.
My best attempt is the following, but I just can't solve it:

```js
function numbers([N], sum) {
  x = 0;
  y = N.length - 1;
  while (x < y) {
    if (N[x] + N[y] == sum)
      return true;
    else if (N[x] + N[y] < sum)
      x++;
    return false
  }

console.log(numbers([5, 2, 1, 9, 15], 6))
```

so if I log the last bit here, I want it to give me index 0 and 2, because they add up to 6.
Hope it makes sense. I am new to coding and have googled to most of it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure about the destructuring `[N]` of the array for taking the first item?

Comment: What if there is more than one couple of numbers matching the condition (e.g. `[5,2,1,9,15,4]`) or if there are repeated numbers in the array (e.g. `[5,2,1,9,15,1]`)?

Comment: Yeah, you need `numbers(N, sum)` or `N` will end up being 5, not the entire array. I'm also not sure about your `else if`; either the two numbers sum up to `sum` or they don't; there's no need for `else if`s here. You're also not testing each pair; you have to use two nested for loops to go through each possible pairing of two numbers.

Comment: Your code is also definitely hitting one of the returns, so only one test takes place, then the function exits. And looking at the curious indentation, `return false` is not subject to the `else if` test.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the indexes that add up to your sum, if one is not found it will return undefined.

```
function numbers(N, sum) {
    indexes = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < N.length; i++){
        let diff = sum - N[i];

        if(indexes[diff] != undefined && indexes[diff] != i){
            return [i, indexes[diff]];
        }else{
            indexes[N[i]] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

This case will return 2 and 0.

```
console.log(numbers([5, 2, 1, 9, 15], 6));
[2, 0]
```

Comment: How do i make it return [0,2] instead? so its the other order

Comment: This code will always return the indexes of the first couple of numbers adding up to the sum but what if the array contains more than one couple of numbers whose sum is 6? For example, try `console.log(numbers([5, 2, 1, 9, 15, 4, 5], 6));`: the function returns only `[0, 2]` while indexes `[1, 5]` and `[2, 6]` are valid results too.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
function numbers(N, sum) {
  let x, y;
  
  for(let y=0;y<N.length;y++) {
    x = 0;
    
    while (x < y) {
      if (N[x] + N[y] == sum) {
        console.log(x, y); //result
        return true;
      } else {
        x++;
      };
    }
  };
  return false;
}

 console.log(numbers([5, 2, 1, 9, 15], 6));
```

The above code will return if it finds the first match. The `x` index needs to be checked against the other indexes (`y`), not only the last index. A `for` loop has been added to go through the possible `y` indexes.

Comment: I am not sure it makes sense to change the order of the array items (by sorting them) when what you want to obtain is their indexes in the array. For example, if you try `console.log(numbers([15, 2, 1, 9, 5], 6));` it will return `0, 2` but the sum of the first element of the array (15) and the third one (1) is 16, not 6.

Comment: Excellent point! It happened to work in that specific case, so I didn't realise. I've updated this answer to exclude that optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work also when there are several couples of addenda giving the desired result and when the numbers array contains duplicated values:

```js
const nums = [5, 2, 1, 9, 15, 4, 5];

function removeDuplicateItems(arr) {
  const stringifiedItemsArr = arr.map(item => JSON.stringify(item));
  const uniqueStringifiedItemsSet = new Set(stringifiedItemsArr);
  return Array.from(uniqueStringifiedItemsSet, JSON.parse);
}

function findAddendaIndexes(numArr, sum) {
  const addendaArr = numArr.reduce((addenda, num, index) => {
    const indexB = numArr.findIndex(item => item + num === sum);
    if (indexB !== -1 && indexB !== index) {
      addenda.push([index, indexB].sort((a, b) => a - b));
    }

    return addenda;
  }, []);

  return addendaArr.length > 0 ? removeDuplicateItems(addendaArr).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]) : null;
}

// test
console.log('numbers:', nums);
console.log('sum 6:', findAddendaIndexes(nums, 6));
console.log('sum 8:', findAddendaIndexes(nums, 8));
console.log('sum 10:', findAddendaIndexes(nums, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = [];
let fun = (arr,value)=>{
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for (let a=0;a<arr.length;a++){
            if (arr[i]+arr[a]===value){
              result.push(arr[a]);
            }
        }
    }
}
fun ([1, 21, 3, 14, 5, 60, 7, 6], 81);  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Something seems wrong with the formatting of your code?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck